# gMail rejects eMails missing MessageID header coming from my Samsung phone

Tags: android, email, samsung, messageid

**Problem:**
gMail rejects emails missing a "MessageID" header, and email originating from my Samsung phone does not include the MessageID header.

**What I see:**
Email originating from my phone's email app [Samsung email Version 6.1.72.1] does not include a message header (*when using my private domain's SMTP server*, parked at GoDaddy/SecureServer.Net).  Therefore, eMail from me/myphone on that account, to any gMail user, is rejected by the Google servers with a 500/550 error, and bounced.

On my phone, other email with another domain includes a MessageID header.  I had assumed that a SMTP server creates that globally unique ID; but since the MessageID does show up on those emails, I'm not sure.

**Other Info:**

1. eMails from my thunderbird client, sending through the same domain/SMTP, *do* include the MessageID
2. emails from my phone client, through *another*, second domain, do include the messageID
3. emails from the WebClient for SecureServer.Net *do* include the MessageID
4. deleting my domain email from the phone app, and recreating it, does not change anything
5. GoDaddy/ReSeller phone-help was not helpful.  That first-layer help asserts that an escalation reported to him that: there is no SMTP server setting which can explain what's going on, and; the expectation is that their SMTP server creates all MessageID headers and puts them in all emails.
6. I am looking at the as-sent, raw emails by sending emails to my domain which I pick up on my Thunderbird.
7. I posted this issue on the Samsung help, and no one has answered.  An earlier, similar question had a single answer, which was to ask Google at the google account help page.  Not helpful, for me.

**So, Questions:**

- Which application client or server is generating the MessageID line, and does email in "sent mail" include a MessageID because the client retrieves the MessageID from the SMTP server as part of the send process?
- **how do I force eMail, from my domain on my Samsung phone's email app, to include a MessageID ...**

**... so I can use my phone to write letters to gMail users**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and was trying to get the messageId into my e-mails.

But the problem was not a wrong client or SMTP server, it was a missing "SPF record" in the DNS records of my domain.
Google changed policies for incoming e-mails, which now require an SPF record.

If you have access to the DNS records of the domain, try to add a TXT field with SPF information.

There are some details regarding SPF:

- https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en
- https://www.validity.com/blog/how-to-build-your-spf-record-in-5-simple-steps/

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue when using the Samsung Mail app. I switched to the MS Outlook App and the issue no longer occurs.

I did not make any changes to SPF records, they were already in place and functional for years.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).